# Redirect traffic based on url to different ip address maintaining port and url information

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite, proxypass

We have a QA version, a UAT version, and a DEV version of webapp. Users need to access these via `http://uat.company.com:41002/webapp`, `http://qa.company.com:41002/webapp`, and `http://dev.company.com:41002/webapp`. There is also a different webapp on port 41001 and also on port 8080 they will need to access.

These url's are required to be available externally to the company, and we only have one public ip address they can be accessed on. As such DNS records need all 3 address to point to one IP. On that single IP address, a server resides running nginx. in the background I need for each url to point to a different server

```
http://uat.company.com --> 123.123.123.1
http://qa.company.com  --> 123.123.123.2
http://dev.company.com --> 123.123.123.3
```

I'm afraid I don't know the correct terminology, however the remainder of the URI and the port must also be carried over to the ip address. I.e. if someone visits

```
http://uat.company.com:41002/webapp/somepage`
```

it will appear as though that is the page they have visited, but really they will be looking at

```
http://123.123.123.1:41002/webapp/somepage
```

or if they visited

```
http://qa.company.com:8080/static/home.html
```

they would really be looking at

```
http://123.123.123.2:8080/static/home.html
```

but their browser would still say `http://qa.company.com:8080/static/home.html`

I have tried

```
server {

    server_name uat.company.com;

    listen 41001;
    listen 41002;
    listen 8080;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://123.123.123.1:$server_port$uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

}

however this gives me a bad gateway 502 page with log: `2015/01/28 16:04:49 [crit] 30571#0: *1 connect() to 123.123.123.1:41002 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.128.245, server: uat.company.com, request: "GET /webapp/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://123.123.123.1:41002/webapp/", host: "uat.company.com:41002"`

I hope this is more clear.

---

**Update**
From Xaviers suggestion that SELinux might have been hampering, I have disabled it and I do get further. Using the nginx config above now seems to be connecting to the second server: The port however is still not carried through. I am calling

```
uat.company.com:41002/webapp/
```

This would, if calling the service directly, redirect to

```
uat.company.com:41002/webapp/spring/config/main
```

However what is happening through the proxy is that it is returning or ending up at

```
uat.company.com/webapp/spring/config/main
```

and thus failing to load a page...

Comment: Probably you don't need nginx, but some iptable config?

Comment: @Alexey We already use nginx to do something similar, however it is more specific, so if we can keep all the config in the same place I'd rather that.

Comment: @AD7six - I have re-written the question entirely. Hopefully this now makes sense, and you will reconsider your downvote if it was you.

Comment: Which Linux distribution is your reverse proxy running?

Comment: Why do you want that weird port numbers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is a Centos 6 box

Comment: @AlexeyTen There are other layers that are involved, these are just the ones we pick to prevent collisions

Comment: In that case, see the linked question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you, but that was only and additional hiccup, and not the solution to the problem, please see my answer and remove the duplicate flag

Comment: We prefer that each question contain only one issue, whenever possible. Your question now contains _two_ distinct and unrelated issues. If you are still having trouble, make the second issue its own question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There is one issue that I was concerned about, and that was the one being asked about and an answer sought. The additional issue was merely a hiccup and is not discussed at any length, and it is this that you are marking as duplicate, not the crux of my question. I can remove all reference to it in my question, but it would make comments and responses no longer make sense. If you prefer I do that anyway then that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have established what the problems were with my setup.

1) SELinux was preventing me from connecting upstream. I have now disabled this and will consider setting it up properly later

2) proxy_pass was doing its job as expected, however the args I needed were `http://123.123.123.1:$server_port/$uri$is_args$args;`

3) `proxy_set_header Host $host` correctly set the hostname back to what I wanted, however it ate the port number. The correct format for my needs is `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port`

There may be neater solutions to this, and I haven't got a full working solution yet as I have cut it down to get it working, however a working section of my config is:

```
server {
    listen 41002;
    server_name uat.comapny.com;

    location /webapp {
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.1:41002/$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    }
}
```

I will post a more generic version once I have fleshed it out. Many thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Did you already have a more generic version?

Comment: @MarcoFranssen No, in the end we needed to create a conf file like this for each environment. We auto-generate it in the build however, so it isn't very painful.

Comment: @MitchKent what did you mean by "more generic"?

Comment: @ppicom unfortunately this is about 6 years old, and I don't recall :)

Comment: Oh! Didn't notice the post's age :D thanks for the reply though! :)

Answer (score 6):

You want to maintain the port, then you should put it in `proxy_pass`.

```
server {

    server_name bob.something.com;

    listen 41001;
    listen 41002;
    listen 8080;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://123.123.123.1:$server_port$uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

You have to realize that this will proxy request through nginx.

Comment: Thank you @Alexey, I have tried this and I get `502 Bad Gateway` page displayed. The nginx log shows `2015/01/28 16:04:49 [crit] 30571#0: *1 connect() to 123.123.123.1:41002 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.128.245, server: bob.something.com, request: "GET /webapp/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://123.123.123.1:41002/webapp/", host: "bob.something.com:41002"`  -  I can wget the url from the nginx box though so not sure what the permission denied is from.

Comment: @MitchKent Check your SELinux policies.

Comment: @XavierLucas Thank you, this has got me further. I will update my question...